# C - 2d string array allocated by dynamic memory

Tags: c, arrays

i recently got into a problem where i'm trying to reallocate memory to
a 2 dimensional char array, but it just does not seems to work.
Here, i'm trying to reallocate the number of reasons to the array reasons by 
multiplying the number of reasons and the size of a char array(string), but it does not work,the 2d array reasons still has 1 cell. Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STR_LEN 50

typedef struct list
{
    char** reasons;
    int numReasons;
}list;

void printReasons(list* pCons, list* pPros,int conNum,int proNum);

int main(void)
{
    list proList = { 0, 1 };
    list conList = { 0, 1 };
    char dillema[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    char stringHelper[STR_LEN] = { 0 };
    int flag = 1, choice = 0;

    conList.reasons = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    proList.reasons = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));

    printf("What is your dillema?\n");
    fgets(dillema, STR_LEN,stdin);

    do
    {
        printf("Choose option:\n1 - Add PRO reason\n2 - Add CON reason\n3 - print reasons\n4 - Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        getchar();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Enter a reason to add to a list PRO:");
            fgets(stringHelper, STR_LEN, stdin);
            stringHelper[strlen(stringHelper) - 1] = 0;

            proList.reasons = (char**)realloc(proList.reasons,sizeof(char*) * proList.numReasons);
            proList.reasons[proList.numReasons - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(stringHelper));

            strcpy(proList.reasons[proList.numReasons - 1], stringHelper);
            proList.numReasons++;
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a reason to add to a list CON:");
            fgets(stringHelper, STR_LEN, stdin);
            stringHelper[strlen(stringHelper) - 1] = 0;

            conList.reasons = (char**)realloc(conList.reasons,sizeof(char**) * conList.numReasons);
            conList.reasons[conList.numReasons - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(stringHelper));

            strcpy(conList.reasons[conList.numReasons - 1], stringHelper);
            conList.numReasons++;
            break;
        case 3:
            printReasons(&conList, &proList,conList.numReasons,proList.numReasons);
            break;
        case 4:
            flag = 0;
            break;
        default:
            printf("choice is not valid,choose again:\n");
        }
    } while (flag);


    getchar();  
    return 0;
}

void printReasons(list* pCons, list* pPros, int conNum, int proNum)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < conNum; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",pCons->reasons[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < proNum; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pPros->reasons[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Review `conList.reasons[conList.numReasons - 1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(stringHelper));

            strcpy(conList.reasons[conList.numReasons - 1], stringHelper);` and consider the _null character_.

Comment: when calling `fgets()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest incorporating the call to `fgets()` as the condition in a `if()` code block

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line. 2) insert a 'reasonable' space: after commas, after semicolons, inside parens, inside brackets, around C operators  3) honor the right margin of the printed page by breaking statements so they do not extend past the right margin.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` so can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: regarding: `proList.reasons = (char**)realloc(proList.reasons,sizeof(char*) * proList.numReasons);`  The field: `proList.numReasons` has not (yet) been incremented,  so the call to `realloc` will do nothing

Comment: note: `realloc` can only be used on allocated memory.  If the code had been checking the returned value, then the code would have caught this.  Also, never assign the returned value from `realloc` directly to the target pointer.  Instead, assign to a 'temp' point, check for != NULL, and if not NULL, then assign 'temp' to the target pointer

Comment: the function: `strlen()`  returns the index to the NUL byte (indexes start at 0, so the returned value cannot be (directly) used to find a NUL byte.  So, this statement: `stringHelper[strlen(stringHelper) - 1] = 0;` would be (safer) written as: `stringHelper[strspn(stringHelper, "\n") ] = '\0';` and, BTW: 0 in an integer, with the contents 0x00000000 and you actually want a single byte I.E. '\0'